# Why would a linker script have multiple section commands?

Tags: embedded, ld

I have been reading the [sections documentation for ld](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/sections.html) and something isn't clear.

Given the partial linker script:

```
MEMORY
{
  FLASH1 (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x000FB000, LENGTH = 0x05000
  FLASH2 (r) : ORIGIN = 0x000FA000, LENGTH = 0x01000
}

SECTIONS
{
  .some_code :
  {
    KEEP(*(SORT(.some_code*)))
  } > FLASH1
}
SECTIONS
{
  .my_page :
  {
    KEEP(*(SORT(.my_page*)))
  } > FLASH2
}
```

Is there ever a reason to have 2 section commands in a single linker script as above rather than having it all in 1 section commands as below?

```
SECTIONS
{
  .some_code :
  {
    KEEP(*(SORT(.some_code*)))
  } > FLASH1
  .my_page :
  {
    KEEP(*(SORT(.my_page*)))
  } > FLASH2
}
```

Or are they equivalent. Are there other cases where you'd want to split it up like that?

Additional clarification: I am asking for a reason to have separate "SECTIONS" commands (each with their own block of section definitions) not asking for the reason for having separate sections in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't ever an unavoidable need to write more than one `SECTIONS` command,
or `MEMORY` command, in a linker script.

```
SECTIONS
{
    /* Commands... */
}
SECTIONS
{
    /* More commands... */
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
SECTIONS
{
    /* Commands... */
    /* More commands... */
}
```

and likewise for `MEMORY`.

However, the maintainability of a non-trivial body of linker-scripts is
assisted if a linker script *can* include multiple `SECTIONS` or `MEMORY`
commands. E.g. if:

**foobar.lds (1)**

```
MEMORY
{
    FOOMEM (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x000FB000, LENGTH = 0x05000
    BARMEM (r) : ORIGIN = 0x000FA000, LENGTH = 0x01000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .foo : {
        *(.foo)
    } > FOOMEM
    .bar : {
        *(.bar)
    } > BARMEM
}
```

were something much less trivial than it is, it might be better refactored as:

**foobar.lds (2)**

```
INCLUDE ./foo.lds
INCLUDE ./bar.lds
```

**foo.lds**

```
MEMORY
{
    FOOMEM (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x000FB000, LENGTH = 0x05000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .foo : {
        *(.foo)
    } > FOOMEM
}
```

**bar.lds**

```
MEMORY
{
    BARMEM (r) : ORIGIN = 0x000FA000, LENGTH = 0x01000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .bar : {
        *(.bar)
    } > BARMEM
}
```

so that `foobar.lds` **(2)** is expanded by the linker to

**foobar.lds (3)**

```
MEMORY
{
    FOOMEM (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x000FB000, LENGTH = 0x05000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .foo : {
        *(.foo)
    } > FOOMEM
}

MEMORY
{
    BARMEM (r) : ORIGIN = 0x000FA000, LENGTH = 0x01000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .bar : {
        *(.bar)
    } > BARMEM
}
```

An historical note: In [this obselete GNU `ld` manual from bygone days](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_chapter/ld_3.html#SEC6),
we can find the constraints:

> You may use at most one SECTIONS command in a script file, but you can have as many statements within it as you wish.

and:

> A command file may contain at most one use of the MEMORY command; however, you can define as many blocks of memory within it as you wish.

which are absent from [the current manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/).